# Angular and bootstrap dropdown. Dealing with href="#"

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, frontend

currently i am dealing with angular nad bootstrap dropdown. The problem is that when i click on dropdown button the angular change his route. So i tried to remove href="#". Next i tried to add target="_self", and also change href parameter to javascript(0).

This is a screen what is happening:

http://imgur.com/XTDY3S8

It doesnt work. I suppose this is because of ng-view container. When i add href="#" it's all fine, because the ng-view  load empty view. I tried to change z-index, positions and other css parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I made a mistake with z-index property and position relative. Now i set it on main navbar container and it works.